# VS Code - toggle search icon in Activity Bar, move from panel or back

Tags: visual-studio-code

I accidentally removed search icon in Activity Bar and don't know how to add it there again. If I click on Activity Bar, I don't see this option any more.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 144, accepted):

**Update**: v1.44 you can now simply **drag many of the views**, including "Search" from the sidebar to the panel and back.  See https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_44#_increased-view-placement-flexibility and https://stackoverflow.com/a/55981465/836330

---

**Update**: v1.42 added a context menu option

`Move to Panel`/`Move to Sidebar`

to certain typically sidebar views like **Search, Outline** and custom views.  So you wouldn't have to use a setting to move the Search view back to the sidebar.    Here is a demo:

[image: search panel location]

Also notice that you no longer right-click in the empty space below the search inputs in the sidebar but on/near the `Search` header itself to bring up the toggle option.

As part of the v1.42 release the **`search.location`** setting mentioned below **will be deprecated**.

> Your setting should migrate automatically, but you will need to use
>   the new generalized method to move the Search view going forward. You
>   do not need to enable the experimental preview setting above in order
>   to move the Search view with the new context menu entry.

So I don't think there is a setting anymore, you just right-click on the header text "Search" whether it is in the Panel or active in the Sidebar to move it.  See the demo below.

Right-click on the "Search" header if you have it in the sidebar to "Move to Panel".

If Search is in the panel, right-click on the word Search to "Move to Sidebar".

To enable moving the Output view at this point, you need to enable `workbench.view.experimental.allowMovingToNewContainer`.

---

There is a new unbound command `workbench.view.search.moveView` which you can use to toggle the search position between the panel and sidebar.  But note that in my testing it only works a couple of times because it focuses the panel when you move search to the sidebar - I'll file a bug.

---

**Previous Answer::**

You may have modified the setting:

```
"search.location": "sidebar",
```

which is the default to the alternative

```
"search.location": "panel",
```

which would put the search widget into the terminal panel as another tab.

---

As of vscode v1.35 or so, you can now `right-click` in the empty space below the search view (i.e., in the sidebar under the open search inputs) and you will get an option to `Toggle Search View Position`.

This context menu switch of the search view is persistent.  It will automatically add this setting to your `settings.json`:

```
  "search.location": "panel",
```

The only way at present (but see edit just below) to move the icon back to the activity bar (and thus the search across files functionality to the sidebar) is to change that setting to the `sidebar` option.  Or look for this setting in the settings editor:

> Search: Location
>
> Controls whether the search will be shown as a view
>   in the sidebar or as a panel in the panel area for more horizontal
>   space.

**EDIT**: More recently, vscode added the abilty to right-click in the search area when it is in the panel to toggle it back to the sidebar.

[image: search view location demo]

Comment: for newer versions of vscode: open settings by `file--> preferences-->settings` or pressing `ctrl+,` and then at `features-->search` change `location` to `sidebar`

Comment: I find it annoying that it is possible to click on something in the UI which takes the search icon out of the sidebar and into a panel, but doesn't have any UI which sends it back the other way. Bad design on somebody's part IMO.

Comment: Wish they would make it so I could drag the Search tab to the Activity Bar. Simple.

Comment: You can drag the search tab to the bottom panel now!

Comment: I can set up everything in VS Code via the JSON settings, but here I have to perform the task manually. Why did they deprecate ` "search.location": "panel",`?

Answer (score 17):

**In windows**

```
file--> preferences-->settings
```

**In mac**

```
preferences -> settings
```

[image]

vs-code version 1.30.2

Comment: In Mac OS "preferences" is not a top level menu item either. I don't know how to refer to it exactly. in this case it would be `Code -> preferences -> settings`

Answer (score 4):

Had this problem recently and "Search" icon was nowhere to be found. One way to reset everything is to run the **Reset View Locations** command from the command palette (cmd/ctrl + shift + p).

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Click on Edit from Navbar
Step 2: Find in Files
.
.
You can easily search for anything in the side paanel
or else if you want anything to search inside files then
Step 1: Click "Ctrl+F"

Comment: just drag this line to activity bar and you are set, thanks mate for helping this short guide